# jquery pass unique id without form

Tags: jquery

```
 $.each(thedata.data, function() {    
 $('#theReturnFormTable').append(         
 '<tr id="newReturn"><td align="center"><a href="##" id="link">'+ this.newrequestor
 +'<input type="hidden" id="theID" value="'+ this.theid +'"></a></td><td
 align="center">'+ this.newthedate +'</td><td>'+ this.theid +'</td><td
 align="center">'+ this.newapproved +'</td>
 <td align="center">'+ this.newsecurityaction +'</td></tr>'
 );
 });
```

Results:

```
requestor=dave theID = 75
requestor=frank theID = 76
requestor=bill theID = 77
requestor=george theID = 78
requestor=sam theID = 79 and so on.
```

I have the link in each row, it grabs theID = 75 no matter row I click on instead of passing the value of theID for that row.  I have brain freeze.  Any Ideas how to pass the value of theID for each row?

Here is where I pass theID to

```
$("#link").live("click", function(){   
//show layer Div
$("#theHover").show();
alert($("#theID").val());
var instance = new readers_cls();
var theID = $("#theID").val();

newdata = instance.getRequestSecurity(theID);
newrooms = instance.getRequestSecurityRooms(theID);
newcust = instance.getRequestSecurityCust(theID);
```

I know it just goes down the page and grabs the first theID in the html.  I need to figure out a way around this.

Comment: You're going to end up with duplicate `id`s in the document. This is going to cause problems.

Comment: yes, ends up with duplicate ids="" in the document, I am looking for a way around this.

Comment: maybe theID'+1'  but then how would I set the Var to call my ajax

Answer (score 0):

you're creating multiple elements with the id 'theID' from the first each loop you posted, that's not good. Why don't you create the element with a proper ID right there and then, so:

```
$.each(thedata.data, function() {    
   $('#theReturnFormTable').append(         
     '<tr id="newReturn"><td align="center"><a href="##" id="link">'+ this.newrequestor
     +'<input type="hidden" id="id_'+this.theid'" value="'+ this.theid +'"></a></td>
     ...
   );
});
```

This way all the hidden input elements will have a uniqui id which you later later pick up...

Comment: id="id_'+this.theid'" creates the unique id for sure, but how do I grab this when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that it's due to the fact that you're giving non-unique IDs to all your elements (since you're assigning static IDs in that code). Use classes and the "this" keyword.

Comment: I ended up using this as the link in the .each 

    <a href="##" id="'+this.theid+'_id" class="thisone">

Then I click the link

    $(".thisone").live("click", function(){ 


 var theID = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[0];

set the id of that row. Works.  Thanks for getting me thinking.